# How to find the neighbour indexes/cells of a base cell at a given radius(Km) in the H3 library

Tags: go, geo, h3

I have no idea how to find the neighbouring cells of the base cell at a given radius(Km). How can I achieve this? If possible for the h3-go library as I am familiar with Go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer here depends on whether you want a true radius check, or a fast approximation using `kRing`. You can find a discussion and example code (in JavaScript) in [this Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@nrabinowitz/h3-radius-lookup). The basic algorithm is

1. Determine the grid cell radius corresponding to the true distance radius you want
2. Call `kRing(origin, gridDistance)` to get the set of cells within that gridDistance.

This is much faster than a true radius check, but slightly less accurate.

Comment: Thank You very much for your reply.

Comment: Happy to help! Remember to mark this as the answer if it answer your question :)